# Create CSV or TXT file in app and save it to 'download' folder - Android

Tags: android, csv, android-download-manager, opencsv, android-storage

I searched and tried a lot before asking this.
But all the code that I'm trying is not working.
I want the file to be stored in the `download` folder and be accessible from the user also if he uninstalls the app.
I also tried using `opencsv` library. Could you provide a `tested` way to create a `csv` or `txt` file and store to `download` folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save to to publicDir(Downloads folder) you first need permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
check [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Note this won't work without permmissions

```
   private void saveData(){

    String csv_data = "";/// your csv data as string;
    File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    //if you want to create a sub-dir
    root = new File(root, "SubDir");
    root.mkdir();

    // select the name for your file
    root = new File(root , "my_csv.csv");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(root);
        fout.write(csv_data.getBytes());

        fout.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        boolean bool = false;
        try {
            // try to create the file
            bool = root.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (bool){
            // call the method again
            saveData()
        }else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create image file");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

Comment: NICE! I had permissions problem... checking again them solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: why do we need write permission for android 11 and above? google chrome does it without any permission